# Why does $PV\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x-1)^2}$ have a finite answer?

Tags: integration, cauchy-principal-value

Mathematica gives the result of the above integral in terms of a Meijer G function, or numerically

$$ PV\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x-1)^2} \approx -0.168 - 2.31 i $$

Ideally I would like to be able to approximate this answer using some numerical integration. But I simply can't understand how there is a finite answer for this. Around the singularity we have

$$ \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x-1)^2}\Bigg|_{x=1-\epsilon} \approx \frac{1}{e}\Big(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} - \frac{2}{\epsilon}+1+O(\epsilon) \Big)$$
$$ \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x-1)^2}\Bigg|_{x=1+\epsilon} \approx \frac{1}{e}\Big(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} + \frac{2}{\epsilon}+1+O(\epsilon) \Big)$$

I can understand how the first order terms will 'cancel' on the left and right sides of the singularity in a principal value sense, but the leading terms both go to infinity in the same direction.

I would appreciate any guidance with understanding this. Thanks!

Edit: The exact expression from Mathematica is

```
-(MeijerG[{{0, 1/2, 1}, {}}, {{1/2, 1}, {}}, -1, 1/2]/\[Pi])
```

which I believe is
$$ -\frac{1}{\pi} G_{3,2}^{2,3}\Big(-1,\frac{1}{2}\Big| \begin{matrix}0,1/2,1\\1/2,1\end{matrix}  \Big) $$

Comment: The integral is divergent. Since the function is positive, nothing changes when you consider the principal value: the integral is divegent.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good way of looking at it. How should I interpret the Mathematica answer then? Is it incorrect?

Comment: Also the integrand is real, but Mathematica's answer is not.  I suspect what's happening here is some sort of analytic continuation.

Comment: It might help if you told us the Meijer G expression Mathematica found.

Comment: This isn't the first time that ${\tt Mathematica}$ yields a $complex\ value$ instead of a $real\ one$. In some cases, I found that adding the ${\tt PrincipalValue \to True}$ option ( even in cases we don't need it ) it yields the right result.

Comment: @FelixMarin Do you mean that it is sometimes incorrectly giving a complex result? I am already using the principal value option to get this answer... without it it tells me it diverges, which is what I expect.

Comment: This might make for an interesting Mathematica.SE question (if versions don't exist already): Why does Mathematica assign a complex PV to this integral?

Comment: There is a nice discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127301/why-this-real-integral-yields-imaginary-results/127315#127315). But I think the focus of my question (maybe I could make it more clear) is: how does this integral even get a PV in the first place?

Comment: The p.v. integral doesn't exist. The finite part integral exists and is real-valued. What you have is
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}
 \int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-x^2}} {(x - 1 - i \epsilon)^2} dx =
\frac {\operatorname {Ei}(1) + \pi \operatorname {erfi}(1)} e -
 \sqrt \pi - 1 - \frac {2 \pi i} e.$$

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same when @Felix Marin's  comment appeared and the result is
$$\frac{\pi \, \text{erfi}(1)+\text{Ei}(1)-e \left(1+\sqrt{\pi }\right)}{e}\sim-0.167837 $$

Comment: I can get basically the same expression by adding a $\delta^2$ in the denominator and evaluating, then expanding in the small $\delta$ limit. I get:
$$\lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x-1)^2 + \delta^2} $$
$$= \lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\pi}{2 e}\frac{1}{\delta}+\frac{\pi \text{erfi}(1)-\Gamma(0,-1)-e(1+\sqrt{\pi}}{e} + O(\delta)$$
The real part of the $\Gamma$ is the same as the $\text{Ei}$. But I am still puzzled about the $1/\delta$ term, the same as the leading terms I describe in the question.